# Running Artisan Command from laravel 4.2 Controller

Tags: php, laravel-artisan, laravel-4.2

I am trying to execute some custom artisan command from controller like

`Artisan::call('php artisan MyCustomCommand');`

but it works fine when I execute

`php artisan MuCustomCommand from CLI`.

I have registered command in `app/start/artisan.php.`
Even `Artisan::call('php artisan --help');` is not working.

Comment: do you see your custom command when you run php artisan ??

Comment: yes, my custom command is there on list of command.

Comment: do you have any error or anything ??

Comment: I think by using laravel 4.2 you can't run the command via code. As their documentation is also not showing any information related to this. As the code which you have used it is available in laravel 5.1 and 5.2 where you have to register your command in `app/Console/Kernel.php` file.

Comment: When Artisan::call('php artisan MyCustomCommand') is executed, it returns
"InvalidArgumentException
Command "php artisan CustomCommand" is not defined."

Comment: For this error registered your CustomCommand class in app.php file e.g. View, Request , Sessions are have aliases.

Comment: @suresh726 did you check the answer  ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should run artisan command like this from your controller . 
Example :

```
 Artisan::call('migrate:install');
```

So Instead of doing `Artisan::call('php artisan MyCustomCommand');`

You should do

```
Artisan::call('MyCustomCommand');
```

Here is the [documentation](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/run-artisan-commands-form-route-or-controller)

Hope it helps :)