# Calling a custom Artisan command in a Controller | Laravel

Tags: laravel, command, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to excute a custom Artisan command in a Controller, but it throws an `CommandNotFound` Exception. In the implementation I run the command, instead of excuting the whole command 'php artisan scan {url}', I just run scan {url} because of this Answer: [Running Artisan Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125338/running-artisan-command-from-laravel-4-2-controller). I don't understand what I did wrong?

**Custom Artisan Command** signature

```
protected $signature = 'scan {url}
                            {--r= : y or n | to follow or not to follow the robot.txt} 
                            {--fm= : set follow mode}
                            {--u= : username} 
                            {--p= : password} 
                            {--s : SQL module} 
                            {--x : XSS module}';
```

**Implementation**

```
switch ($select) {

   case 'full':

     \Artisan::call('scan ' . $customer->cms_url); //url == http://localhost:8888
     return $request;

     break;
}
```

**Error**

```
1/1) CommandNotFoundException
There are no commands defined in the "scan http" namespace.
in Application.php (line 548)
at Application->findNamespace('scan http')
in Application.php (line 582)
at Application->find('scan http://localhost:8888')
in Application.php (line 205)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First register your Artisan command in `app/console/Kernel.php`: in commands array add your command Class. After that you can call your command like this

```
\Artisan::call('scan', ['url' => "{$customer->cms_url}"]);
```

You must wrap the url in `" "` otherwise it will not set the full string

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
\Artisan::call('database:backup');//database:backup is a command
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.